# How to iterate through object inside object values

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const schoolArr = {
  class10: { 
           studentInfo: {name: 'John'}, 
           exam: {result: 'pass'} 
           },
  class11: { 
           studentInfo: {name: 'Alis'}, 
           exam: {result: 'pass'} 
           },
  class12: { 
           studentInfo: {name: 'Nick'}, 
           exam: {result: 'fail'} 
           }
};
```

How to create list of studentName if result is pass. class10,11,12 all are dynamic values.I am stuck at how to access this dynamic value in iteration.

I want result like array of `student = [John, Alis]`

Comment: previous question?  `Object.values(schoolObj).filter(e => e.exam.result ==='pass').map(e => e.studentInfo.name)`

Comment: @ivanChew
I had to delete earlier one as was not able to edit question. Thanks for you time. If you see my edited question here.

Comment: @cmgchess yes edited as it was incorrect structure. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Unless John, Alis, Nick, pass and fail are variables put them in quotes... (and don't have the same key multiple times in an object unless you for some strange reason intend to overwrite that key...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to the updated object structure:

1. Filter the object values.
2. Map to get the names

*Note:* You can destructure objects in multiple levels.

*Also note:* You can't use the same key in an object multiple times without overwriting the previous entry with that key, so this seems like a strange structure since you can only have one student in every class if you use it...

```
const schoolArr = {
  class10: {
    studentInfo: { name: 'John' },
    exam: { result: 'pass' }
  },
  class11: {
    studentInfo: { name: 'Alis' },
    exam: { result: 'pass' }
  },
  class12: {
    studentInfo: { name: 'Nick' },
    exam: { result: 'fail' }
  }
};

console.log(
  Object.values(schoolArr)
    .filter(({ exam: { result } }) => result === 'pass')
    .map(({ studentInfo: { name } }) => name)
);
```

Comment: If you can check corrected structure.
Yes fixed structure and added quotes. Thanks

Comment: I have answered you - the solution is working - have you tried running it?

Before you deleted your question you also got another answer, showing that you can use reduce as well. That answer was also a working solution :)

Ah, saw now that you added another object level, fine I'll fix

Comment: I modified object as I have name and result in different object inside object. Modifed key name as earlier one was duplicated.

Checking your asnwer. will update you here. Thanks a lot for your time